# Align image to the right

Tags: html

So I am very new to the whole coding thing and for this site I am building for class I want to align this photo I have at the bottom and move it to the right hand side of the page.

```
<img src ="halogram%20VR.jpg" alt = "man in halogram type VR setting" width:"200" height= "200">
```

This is the code for the image and I tried to add put something like `align=center`, but that has presented no results. What is the proper code for moving my image to the right hand side of the page?

Comment: either you made an error or forgot to add the code. Welcome to stack overflow in any case. Please read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to create a good question.

Comment: if you work with an external css sheet, add to your image a `float:right` .. see here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: You will need to add more information such as the HTML surrounding the image. BTW there is a typo `width:` should be `width=`

Comment: @Ramineghbalian we talk about a horizontal align, not a vertical align :-)

Answer (score 1):

While you can use `float:right` that will mean you need to clear that `float` for anything after that element. You can use `text-align` on the parent element for a simpler option:

```css
div {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/example-sign-paper-origami-speech-260nw-1164503347.jpg" />
</div>
```

An example of `float` messing up your layout without `clear`ing it (note that this looks fine on Stackoverflow's small width, clicking `full page` will show the actual result).

```css
img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/example-sign-paper-origami-speech-260nw-1164503347.jpg" />
  <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
</div>
<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
```

An example using flexbox

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/example-sign-paper-origami-speech-260nw-1164503347.jpg" />
</div>
```

An example using `float` and `clear`ing:

```css
.clear::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
} 

.float {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="clear">
  <div class="float">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/example-sign-paper-origami-speech-260nw-1164503347.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<p>HELLO WORLD</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your HTML with `<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" style="float: right">` or in a seperate .css file with `img {float: right;}`